# Processmaker javascript/node executor uses node 14

Tags: processmaker

Node 14 was released in 2021 - https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.17.3
The latest processmaker (2023 fall) still uses this.

Is there a way of getting an Executor that uses a later version of node?
Even better - can I just give my own dockerfile and use that as an executor?